# How to access locals data in javascript part of index.ejs (view)?

Tags: javascript, express

I am using Express.js and sending a get request and trying to use the response in the javascript part of the view (EJS template)

```
 <% if(locals.results) { %>

 <% results.forEach(function( result ) { %>
```

but I can't use this within script tag to access the results.

(This is working to print results in html tags but I want to pass it to a javascript function)

Comment: What template engine are you using?

Comment: He's using EJS @Brad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a work around by adding response text to hidden paragraph elements and reading them in javascript